# Programmatically using smartcard to login onto Active Directory (C#)

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory, smartcard, x509

Here is my scenario:

I have a client application running outside the domain, on a computer outside the domain.

My application needs to prompt the user to login with smart-card, and use the x.509 certificate on the card to authenticate against active directory.

While I did find some libraries that give access to the smartcard, I can't seem to find the right API to extract the certificate from the smart card (or from the store), and validate it against the AD.

Also, I am kind of lost on the many differnet libraries and framework: WCF, WSE (kerberos, x.509?), cryptoAPI etc.

To make my question focuesd: what would be the best direction in order to allow a user to login to a domain from my client application?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using ActiveDirectory then you could have those users if authenticated or on the same Domain, add a group to AD and go from there.. does this make sense..?

Comment: I do have an ActiveDirectory. The question is how to do the authentication process programatically (the machine is not in domain, and so the user-sesssion). Hope I made it clear.

Comment: if the machine is not in the domain but the user account is then you could use DirectorySearcher object to verify that way.. otherwise you would either have to use some sort of SQL Server authentication or some other means of authentication.. I need you to explain a little bit more clear so I can advise on a proper means thanks

Comment: @DJKRAZE - thanks for the willingness!

The Computer is not in the domain, and so is the user account not in the domain. 

I need to enable a user to authenticate herself against the domain (using smart-card). Usually, users of this domain are required to user smart-card authentication on their "regular" workstations.

Comment: don't give up quite yet... I will look for something really quick.. try this site it has a step by step on how to setup using IIS hope this helps http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2010/05/smart-card-authentication-module-update.html  this google search link will help too hopefully http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+Authenticate+Users+against+SmartCard&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=

Comment: Thanks, I  had this site. Bear in mind that this is a winforms application. So I can't have IIS do all the work for me and just web-config it.

Comment: I was not aware it was a winforms app however you actually could have IIS do it especially if you were consuming a Web Service in your windows application.. just an fyi